# What does self mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, self

What does ruby `self` represent? what is it? what does it mean? Could some please explain it to me? in simple terms please
And what is its function in a class?

```
class MyClass
   def method.self
   end
end
```

Comment: Where you saw this piece of code? I think, `self` is misplaced.. :) Please read through this [blog](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby/) to understand what is `self` ..

Comment: It is explained in Ruby Documentation- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-self.  Have a look at [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure that you have done sufficient research and post specific question.

Comment: @WandMaker Help us to close this question.. :)

Comment: The book _The Well-Grounded Rubyist_ covers _self_ quite well I think.

Comment: You need to do more research before asking: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`self` refers to the object that is currently in context.

In your example, `self` is the `class` itself and `def self.method` is defining a class method. For example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.method
    puts "Hello!"
  end
end

> MyClass.method
#=> "Hello"
```

You can also use `self` on instances of a class.

```
class MyClass
  def method_a
    puts "Hello!"
  end

  def method_b
    self.method_a
  end
end 

> m = MyClass.new
> m.method_b
#=> "Hello!"
```

In this case, `self` refers to the instance of `MyClass`.

There is a good blog post on [self in Ruby here](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby/), or, as it was pointed out in the comments, there is some more on this in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-self).

Comment: It is like "this.myObject" in java? Does it similar?

Comment: `self` could very well have been called `this` in Ruby, so yes, it is similar.

Comment: Cool..!! Thanks a lot!